# Can SQL queries have subqueries in the from clause?

Tags: mysql, sql

I've written the following query that is supposed to find the max sum of all wages of every staff member. For some reason mysql doesn't seem to like the the sub query in the from clause.

```
select max(sumwages)
from
(select staff.name, sum(wages) as sumwages
from staff, schedule
where staff.ssn = schedule.ssn
group by staff.ssn)
```

I also wrote this simpler query to test my theory. This also gives a syntax error. Is what I'm trying to do even possible or do I have to find another way?

```
select *
from (select ssn from staff)
```

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=6984f1fcee48b73c8e5dc63265e4308a

Answer (score 6):

Yes.  In MySQL, these are referred to as derived tables.  And every derived table requires an alias:

```
select max(sumwages)
from (select staff.name, sum(wages) as sumwages
      from staff join
           schedule
           on staff.ssn = schedule.ssn
      group by staff.ssn
     ) ss;
```

Also note the use of proper, explicit, **standard**, readable `JOIN` syntax.  *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.

Answer (score 1):

Additionally - you may avoid the subquery by

```
select sum(wages) as sumwages
from staff, schedule
where staff.ssn = schedule.ssn
group by staff.ssn
ORDER BY sumwages DESC LIMIT 1
```

This will give one row with maximal sum too...